# Swift: Passing Data Between UITabViews & Allowing Global Access to Data

Tags: ios, swift, uitabview

First off, let me explain my app and its flow.  The app opens, and the user creates a profile (stores all the data in a dictionary of type `[String: Any]`).  After the user clicks on create, it sends them to a Console Screen (which displays parts of the information the user input, such as their name through a `segue`).  Theres a tab that lets them EDIT their profile (name, weight, address, etc).  When the user edits their info (to change their name, weight, etc), it should also update the info displayed on the Console Page.

My main question is, how do I structure it so the data is universally available to all of the tab views.  More specifically, so the data is NOT an INSTANCE or copy of the data.  I've created a class called `Person` which has all of the variables stored in it (`firstName`, `lastName`, etc).  I've tried declaring the instance of the person class as a variable before the `UIViewController` class declaration, but it won't let me use the `UITextField` `.text` property (because they havent been created yet...?).

Here is my Person class...

```
class Person {

    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var phoneNumber: String
    var weight: Int
    var gender: String
    var streetAddress: String
    var cityState: String

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String, phoneNumber: String, weight: Int, gender: String, streetAddress: String, cityState: String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.phoneNumber = phoneNumber
        self.weight = weight
        self.gender = gender
        self.streetAddress = streetAddress
        self.cityState = cityState
    }
}
```

I have also subclassed the `UITabBarController` as `TabBarViewController` because I've read that you can send the data to that subclassed `viewController` and make it universally available to all of the imbedded tabs.  I'm just at a loss as to how it all works.

I apologize for possibly asking a repeat question...I have look/researched this and I haven't found any suitable solutions for my particular case.

Updated code to save data as `CoreData`...

```
    guard let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
    }
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
let userInfo = PInfo(firstName: firstNameField.text, lastName: lastNameField.text, cityState: cityStateField.text, streetAddress: streetAddressField.text, gender: genderInputField.text, userWeight: 200)

save(withPersonInfo: userInfo, withContext: managedContext)
```

I'm able to access the data in various `viewControllers`, but it gives it back to me as a single item array...  Ideally, I'd like to have them as `key:value` pairs so I can easily set them to display and are editable in the `Edit Profile` `viewController`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be `Delegates`. The class where you are getting the data would sets your delegate, and anyone else who wishes to get that subscribe to that delegate.

As matter of fact: I think using  `Delegate + CoreData` might save you from troubles; Listen for data then saved that data. Now your other controllers will do a quick fetch (core data is so fast man:) for that one user scenario )

Some code:

```
class PersonDetail: NSManagedObject { // this is how your coreData's Entity should look like 
    @NSManaged public var firstname: String?
    @NSManaged public var lastname:  String?

    // add the other fields, such as weight 

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<PersonDetail> {
        return NSFetchRequest<PersonDetail>(entityName: "PersonDetail")
    }
}
// This struct would to get the data from the user 
struct PInfo {
    var firstname:String?
    var lastname:String?
}
// this function would get an instance of that PInfo 
// for example var p = PInfo(firstname:"Stack",lastname:"Overflow")

func save(withPersonInfo p:PInfo, withContext context:NSManagedObjectContext) {
    let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "PersonDetail", in: context)
    let managedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entityDescription!, insertInto: context) as! PersonDetail
    // this is where I am passing data into the entity 
    managedObject.firstname = p.firstname
    managedObject.lastname = p.lastname

    try? context.save() // use the proper do {} catch, I was saving time lol :)

}
// when you fetch from coreData you have an instance of PInfo

func fetchSingleUser(withContext context:NSManagedObjectContext) -> PInfo {
    let request:NSFetchRequest<PersonDetail> = PersonDetail.fetchRequest()
    let coreData_items = try? context.fetch(request)

   guard let items = coreData_items,
       let firstItem = items.first  // since we only have one user
       else {  fatalError("Error while querying")  }

    return PInfo(firstname: firstItem.firstname, lastname:firstItem.lastname)
}
```

Comment: So I think using `CoreData` is a good idea here since I have multiple `attributes`.  I've gotten the data to save as an array, but how do I make it save as a dictionary?  I've read to use a plist, but I feel like `CoreData` should be able to handle dictionaries.  I've updated my original question to provide the code I have for saving the data into a `CoreData` `array`...

Comment: I add it some code, but I didnt use a dictionary instead a simple `struct`, and when you fetch that data a new instance of that struct @RyanSady

Comment: Thank you @Lamar!  I'm having an issue where its finding `nil` when trying to save the data.  I'm not quite sure where it's coming from though, as I'm very new with CoreData and it's workings...  I've updated the original question with the code I'm using to save the data.  I've added the `cityState` `streetAddress` `gender` & `userWeight` variables in the `PersonDetail` and `PInfo` classes.

Comment: Did you add the attribute inside your entity from coreData model

Comment: I did.  I believe it has something to do with the `let managedObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entityDescription!, insertInto: context) as! PersonDetail` (due to debugging/console logging).  I'm not sure I'm setting/creating a `context` properly...

Comment: Remember in my example PersonDetail is the name of my managedObject & I think yours is Person

Comment: I finally figured it out.  Thanks!  It's pulling data from some random source (not quite sure from WHERE)..it's definitely not taking the `textFields.text` data...  That part I can figure out on my own.  I just need to figure out how to access the fetched data entries.  I appreciate all the help @Lamar!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One very easy solution is to give your app delegate a `person` property initialized as an empty Person. This solves the problem because *every* class can access that property:

```
let p = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).person
```

Moreover, `p` obtains this Person by reference, so any changes to its properties are reflected back into the `person` property itself, ready to be seen (and mutated) by the next view controller.

A more sophisticated, satisfying solution, since there is only *one* user to be configured, would be to have the Person class itself dispense a `shared` person instance as a singleton. (Do a search on SO to learn how to implement Singleton in Swift.) Again, that singleton will be universally available:

```
let p = Person.shared()
```